# Index in Google Trends

Tags: trends

For a research project, I am attempting to create a model that uses google trends results as its independent variable. As you probably know, google trends standardises its outputs on a scale from 0-100. The goal is to find out whether an increase in searches for particular words results in higher unemployment rates. Google trends has the option to select an index relating to unemployment already. However, I would like to select the words that are in the index myself. For simplicity, I really want to combine these words into a single index and not obtain their search results separately. Unfortunately the option to search for a combination of words in an index has not been given by google trends as for as I know. Is there a way to compromise the outputs into one single independent variable?

Comment: Are you sure/ have you tried queries such as: "(term1, term2)"

Answer (score 0):

Great! I'm working on a similar project, too. You can use average of those queries and create an index. Let $X_1, X_2, ...$ are your queries from Google Trends, so you can simply generate GTI=mean($X_i$).

Comment: can you clarify this a little bit? the run on sentences look like there's a question in the middle of them.

Comment: Dear @albert, the challenge is how to create an Index for some Auxiliary variables, say **`X_1, X_2, ...`**. Any idea?

Comment: no ideas whatsoever